# Docker Fig MongoDB Master Slave

Tags: mongodb, fig

im really new to docker and fig, maybe fig isnt the right tool.
I try to get a master slave mongodb construct running on my machine.

what i did so far in fig (fig.yml)

```
redis:
  image: redis
  ports:
      - "6379:6379"

mongomaster:
  image: mongo
  ports:
      - "27017:27017"

mongoslave1:
  image: mongo
  links: 
      - mongomaster

mongoslave2:
  image: mongo
  links: 
      - mongomaster
```

would this be the right way to do this ? or would i use fig scale ?

how can i pass the slave parameter like here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/master-slave/

```
mongod --slave --source <masterhostname><:<port>>
```

to make my mongoslave[1-2] a real slave of mongomaster ?

My aim is to type **fig up** and the 2 slaves should be the slave of mongomaster

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a command to specify the host

```
mongoslave1:
  image: mongo
  links: 
  - mongomaster
  command: mongod --slave --source mongomaster
```